# How to make protractor test fail if function fails?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, jasmine, protractor

So basically I have some helpers method to help me debug my protractor test cases, one of my main ones is tho wait for an element to be clickable, I'm creating this loop to give the necessary time for protractor to find and make sure the element is enabled, but when an element is not found, either by the element not being found or a typo on my scrip, I would like the test run to STOP and mark it as a FAILURE..

```
 async WaitToBeClickable(element){
       try{
           for(var i = 0; i <= 3000; i++){
               var wait = await browser.wait(this.EC.elementToBeClickable(element), i);
               if(wait == true){
                   break;
               }else{
                   //this is where I want to fail
               }
           }
       }catch(err){
           //this is where I want to fail
           await console.log(`WAIT TO BE CLICKABLE FAILED:\n${element.parentElementArrayFinder.locator_.value}\n\nError:\n${err}\n`);
       }
   };
```

this would help me a LOT debugging my script since I'm working on VSC, but I can not seem to find a way yet to make the test FAIL and thereby to CLOSE the browser at the first fail, I've seen protractor-fail-fast and protractor-bail-fast but it seems to be for the jasmine test cases not for function, I WOULD REALLY APPRECIATE any help please, protractor its driving me a bit nuts lol...

Answer (score 2):

```
//method

const checkData = () = {
     return new Promise((resolve)=>{
           if(true){
               // Success case
               return resolve(true)
           }
           else{
               // Fail case
               return reject(false)
           }
  })
}


//Specfile

it('sample test',async ()=>{
    Let data = await checkData();
    expect(data).toEqual(true);
})
```

Based on resolved value test will pass or fail

Answer (score 2):

If you function throws error you can just use the `done` function that jasmine provides

Example:

```
it('should do something', async done => {

    try {
        await weDoSomething();
    } catch (e) {
        done.fail(e); // mark test as failed
    }

    done(); // mark test as done
}, 1 * 60 * 1000);

async function weDoSomething() {
    throw Error('failed function');
}
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Works great. Doesn't stop any future tests.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try simply re-throwing the error in the catch? I believe that should cause the test to fail.

**Comments**:

You do not need to await a console.log as it is an synchronous operation. 
`broser.wait`s throw exceptions when the element is not found within the timeout period, it appears your for loop is not required at all.

This function will wait 3000ms for the element to be clickable and if that does not happen it will throw an exception which will be caught in the catch. It will log the message and then rethrow the error which will fail your test (assuming the error is not being caught and handled further up)

```
async WaitToBeClickable(element){
  try {
    await browser.wait(this.EC.elementToBeClickable(element), 3000);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`WAIT TO BE CLICKABLE FAILED:\n${element.parentElementArrayFinder.locator_.value}\n\nError:\n${err}\n`);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```