# Expect().toBe(true) condition in if statement not working as expected

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor with selenium and was trying to check the element present using the expect() condition with in the if statement, but it is going to else block even though the condition is true. In the condition I tried both toBe and toEqual and both has same effect.

```
let email_Original = element(by.css('button[value="original"][aria-pressed="true"]'))
var isTranslated = await email_Original.isPresent()
    console.log('Translate button state is ' + isTranslated)
    if (expect(isTranslated).toBe(true)) {
      console.log('Pass: Email successfully translated to original language')
    } else {
      console.log('Fail: Email not translated to original language')
    }

output
Translate button state is true 
Fail: Email not translated to original language
```

Comment: Why????????? `if (isTranslated) {}` should be enough. There is no reason for an assertion here. This is not the right way to use an `expect()`.

Comment: I was using that before and that time its working fine. The main reason of using expect() is currently without the expect() when the test fails and goes to else block it prints the statement but at the end of the test it still says 0 failures. So I want to use expect() so I can get the number of actual test cases failed. Is there any other way that I can do to get the failures ex. 27 specs, 2 failures

Comment: Do you really need the logging message? You could just get rid of the if/else block and do `expect(isTranslated).toBe(true)`. The message from a failed test would say something like `expected 'false' to be 'true'`. If you set a good description you will know what failed. `it('should be translated', () => {})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the logging messages and just use the assertion to tell you if it passed or not.

```
it('should be translated', async () => {
  const email_Original = element(by.css('button[value="original"][aria-pressed="true"]'));
  const isTranslated = await email_Original.isPresent();
  expect(isTranslated).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with the solution mentioned in this page. I used done callback 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514860/how-to-make-protractor-test-fail-if-function-fails

Comment: Your solution works only when you want to show the failures, but I need pass message also, so done call back does both for me